# The hyperref numbered item in a yellow highlighted box instead of only a rounded box

Tags: hyperref, boxes

I want all the hyperref numbered item in a yellow highlighted box.

See the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Main result}
\begin{theorem} \label{Th}
Statement of this theorem.
\end{theorem}
%
Using the Theorem \ref{Th}, I want to show something.


Here, instead of red coloured rounded box I want a fully highlighted
yellow box as like we generally do in pdf file to highlight some text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Before adding new 'I want' it would be very nice to accept answers to your questions (and many of them have answers!)

Comment: for a fully coloured box there is no any answer. Answers are available only for rounded coloured box.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example we can use that replicates your current setup? It's not entirely clear what you mean by "a rounded box"?

Comment: Dear Werner, please suggest me.

Comment: For example highlighted coloured box for Theorem 1.3.2. and for such type of hyperref number everywhere in the document.

Comment: Please add a small complete (=compiling) document to your post (use the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/346824/edit)) that contains  elements that you want to have colored. (This is what Werner is asking for.) Moreover, go through the [list of your previous questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/41617/deepesh-patel#change-post-sort) and mark those answers that solved your problem with a green check mark, by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer. (This is what Christian is asking for.)

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Main result}
\begin{theorem} \label{Th}
Statement of this theorem.
\end{theorem}
%
Using the Theorem \ref{Th}, I want to show something.


Here, instead of red coloured rounded box I want a fully highlighted yellow box as like we generally do in pdf file to highlight some text.
\end{document}

Comment: I don't see a red coloured box. Maybe you have an old version of hyperref? Or do you generate something different than PDF?

Comment: @PietvanOostrum: I think the O.P. means the red frame of the link box

Comment: I don't see such a red box.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum: It is there, around the theorem number `1.1`

Comment: The red box seems to be an Acrobat (Reader) feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red boxes can be disabled with

```
\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0}
```

There seems to be no official way to highlight the links (or otherwise change the apparearance, other than color them), as far as I can see. So that means the only way is to go into the internals of `hyperref`, which of course is a big NO, NO!

That said, adding this to the preamble (after loading hyperref) this will put a yellow highlight on them:

```
\usepackage{soul}
\makeatletter
\let\saved@hyper@link\hyper@link
\def\hyper@link#1#2#3{\saved@hyper@link{#1}{#2}{\hl{#3}}}
\makeatother
```

[image]